# use adb to take a screenshot of the emulator but the image file is corrupted

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, android-emulator, adb

I am using adb, subprocess and memuc(MEmu Command) to take a screenshot with a specific coordinate. I originally saved the image in png format, but the image file got corrupted, then I tried to save it as jpg but still got the same error. Then I pulled that image (both formats) to the computer and tried to open it, the message appeared as shown below.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPXQT.png)
And below is my code:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
from time import sleep

# Take a screenshot using adb and save it to the /sdcard/ directory on the emulator
command = 'memuc -i 1 adb "shell screencap -p -d 161,631,554,334 /sdcard/screenshot.jpg"'
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

if process.returncode == 0:
    sleep(5)
    command2 = 'memuc -i 1 adb "pull /sdcard/screenshot.jpg"'
    process2 = subprocess.Popen(command2, shell=True, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)
    stdout2, stderr2 = process2.communicate()

    if process2.returncode == 0:
        os.remove("screenshot.jpg")
```

Can someone explain this to me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`screencap` help says

```
-d: specify the physical display ID to capture (default: <id>)
```

so it's expecting a display ID.

Also, `-p` is

```
   -p: save the file as a png.
```

and you are giving a `.jpg` extension (*while this really doesn't matter it would be confusing for sure*)

#### update

check https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/adbclient/screenshot-box for a tool that allows you to specify the coordinates

Comment: i consulted a lot of sources, and they say that the display ID is the coordinates behind it (in my code it's "161,631,554,334"). And for -p I have tested by saving many different image formats, it still works properly when capturing the whole screen. The error only occurs when I try to make it capture only the part I want

Comment: Yes, because you are providing an **invalid** display ID, the valid ones can be obtained by `dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --display-id`

Comment: It works properly when you capture the entire screen because you are not providing an invalid display ID, that simple.

Comment: I tried searching your way, the results returned like this: https://imgur.com/ej51NFA Is the red circled the ID? Sorry for asking a lot since I'm a newbie

Comment: Example: `$ dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --display-id` returns 
`Display 123456789012345678 (HWC display 0): port=129 pnpId=QCM displayName=""`

Comment: then I just need to add the coordinates after the ID is it ok?

Comment: check `screencap` help and verify it supports coordinates (mine doesn't)

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/74893141/236465